# Matplotlib: orthographic projection of 3D data (in 2D plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d, projection, orthographic

I'm trying to plot 3D data in 2D using orthographic projection. Here is partially what I'm looking for:

[image: Graph obtained by the following code]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),facecolor='white')
axs = [fig.add_subplot(223)]
axs.append(fig.add_subplot(224))#,sharey=axs[0]))
axs.append(fig.add_subplot(221))#,sharex=axs[0]))
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
values = rng.random((100,3))-.5
values[:,1] = 1.6*values[:,1]
values[:,2] = .5*values[:,2]

for ax,axis in zip(axs,['y','x','z']):
    axis1,axis2={'x':(1,2),'y':(0,2),'z':(0,1)}[axis]
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle([0,0], radius=.2, color='pink',zorder=-20))
    ax.scatter(values[:,axis1],values[:,axis2])
axs[0].set_xlabel('x')
axs[2].set_ylabel('y')
axs[1].set_xlabel('y')
axs[0].set_ylabel('z')
fig.subplots_adjust(.08,.06,.99,.99,0,0)
plt.show()
```

There are some issues with this plot and the fixes I tried: I would need 'equal' aspect so that the circles are actually circle. I would also need the circles to be of the same size in each subplot. Finally, I would like the space to be optimized (i.e. with as little white space inside and between the subplots as possible).

I have tried sharing the axis between the subplots, then doing `.axis('scaled')` or `.set_aspect('equal','box',share=True)` for each axes, but the axis end up not being properly shared, and the circle in each subplot end up of different sizes. And while it crops the subplots to the data, it leaves a lot of space between the subplots. `.axis('equal')` or `.set_aspect('equal','datalim',share=True)` without axis shared leaves white space inside the subplots, and with shared axis, it leaves out some data.

Any way to make it work? And it would be perfect if it can work on matplotlib 3.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work using gridspec (I changed scatter for plot to visually make sure no data gets left out). It requires some tweaking of the figsize to really minimize the white space within the axes. Thank you to `@jylls` for the intermediate solution.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

%matplotlib inline
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
values = rng.random((100,3))-.5
values[:,1] = 1.6*values[:,1]
values[:,2] = .5*values[:,2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8),facecolor='white')
ranges = np.ptp(values,axis=0)
gs = GridSpec(2, 2, None,.08,.06,.99,.99,0,0, width_ratios=[ranges[0], ranges[1]], height_ratios=[ranges[1], ranges[2]])
axs = [fig.add_subplot(gs[2])]
axs.append(fig.add_subplot(gs[3]))#,sharey=axs[0]))
axs.append(fig.add_subplot(gs[0]))#,sharex=axs[0]))

for ax,axis in zip(axs,['y','x','z']):
    axis1,axis2={'x':(1,2),'y':(0,2),'z':(0,1)}[axis]
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle([0,0], radius=.2, color='pink',zorder=-20))
    ax.plot(values[:,axis1],values[:,axis2])
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')

axs[0].set_xlabel('x')
axs[2].set_ylabel('y')
axs[1].set_xlabel('y')
axs[0].set_ylabel('z')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph obtained from the code]

Comment: Good to hear you found what you were looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common `xlim`, `ylim` for your subplots and set your equal ratio with `ax.set_aspect(aspect='equal', adjustable='datalim')`:
See full code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),facecolor='white')

axs = [fig.add_subplot(223)]
axs.append(fig.add_subplot(224))#,sharey=axs[0]))
axs.append(fig.add_subplot(221))#,sharex=axs[0]))
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
values = rng.random((100,3))-.5
values[:,1] = 1.6*values[:,1]
values[:,2] = .5*values[:,2]


for ax,axis in zip(axs,['y','x','z']):
    axis1,axis2={'x':(1,2),'y':(0,2),'z':(0,1)}[axis]
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle([0,0], radius=.2, color='pink',zorder=-20))
    ax.scatter(values[:,axis1],values[:,axis2])
    ax.set_xlim([np.amin(values),np.amax(values)])
    ax.set_ylim([np.amin(values),np.amax(values)])
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')

axs[0].set_xlabel('x')
axs[2].set_ylabel('y')
axs[1].set_xlabel('y')
axs[0].set_ylabel('z')
fig.subplots_adjust(.08,.06,.99,.99,0,0)
plt.show()
```

The output gives:
[image]

Comment: That's pretty good! Any way to change the axes sizes to crop out the white space?

Comment: The white spaces come from setting the `xlim`` and the `ylim`. You can remove the lines   `ax.set_xlim([np.amin(values),np.amax(values)])` and `ax.set_ylim([np.amin(values),np.amax(values)])`. The difference is that your circles will then look like they have different size.

Comment: I mean like similarly to using `.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')`, but with proper axis sharing / with the same size, and ideally without gaps between subplots. The results is better than what I had, but it's still missing that it has a lot of unneccassary space within the axes. I'll try to see if something can be done to that using gridspec.

Comment: There isn't any gaps between subplots on my plot? The white spacing in your solution comes form using `adjustable='box'`. Try using `adjustable='datalim'`  instead (see code in  answer)